# Unable to enter texts in passcode textfields for iOS UI testing

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, xcode6, ios-ui-automation

Here's my code to run the UI test on Xcode:

```
     var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
     var app = target.frontMostApp();

     var window = app.mainWindow();

     //display the current screen 
     target.logElementTree();

     //set value as email address
     window.textFields()[0].setValue("test11@test.com");
     //set value in passcode 
     window.textFields()[1].setValue("1234");


     window.buttons()["SIGN IN"].tap();
```

And the app interface looks like this:
[image]

For the line:

```
    Window.textFields()[0].setValue("1234");
```

it shows:

```
    Unexpected error in -[UIATextField_0x7fc8ac0e360 setValue:],/SourceCache/UIAutomation_Sim/UIAutomation-430.2.1/Frameworks/UIElement.m.line 1088, kAXErrorCannotComplete
```

So it works when the scripts enter the email address, but not the passcode. I am thinking the app detects that the passcode is entered by a robot, not a human. That's why it produces error? If so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a security problem.

[image]

Just uncheck the circled box for testing reason, then problem fixed!!

Answer (score 1):

You could leave the "Secure text field" box checked in Interface Builder and refer to it using `window.secureTextFields` instead of `window.textFields`